# Very stubborn wp_register_script / add_action vs remove

Tags: plugins, filters, wp-enqueue-script, actions

I am trying to get rid of a plugin's .js file in the  but it's not working.

It's being called here {partial code):

```
class awqsf{

  const post_type = 'awqsf';

  function __construct(){       
    // style for front end
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'awsqf_front_styles'), false, '1.0', 'all',1 );           
  }

  function awsqf_front_styles(){
    wp_register_script( 'awqsf-frontjs', plugins_url( 'js/awqsf-front.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script('awqsf-frontjs');
  }

} //end class
```

I have tried a lot of different versions, wp_deregister_script and remove_action, but can't seem to get rid of it:

```
//deregister awqsf
function my_deregister_scripts() {
  //wp_register_script( 'awqsf-frontjs', plugins_url( 'js/awqsf-front.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0' ); // the original wp_register_script
  wp_deregister_script( 'awqsf-frontjs', 'http://www.spijkerbroek.me/wp-content/plugins/advance-wp-query-search-filter/js/awqsf-front.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );
  wp_deregister_script("wp_enqueue_scripts", 'http://www.spijkerbroek.me/wp-content/plugins/advance-wp-query-search-filter/js/awqsf-front.js', array("awqsf","awsqf_front_styles"), false, '1.0', 'all',1 );    
  wp_deregister_script( 'awqsf-frontjs', array('http://www.spijkerbroek.me/wp-content/plugins/advance-wp-query-search-filter/js/awqsf-front.js', 'jquery'), false, '1.0', 'all',1 );
  wp_deregister_script('awqsf','awqsf-front.js');
  wp_deregister_script('awqsf');
  //function awsqf_front_styles(){} // the function
  //add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'awsqf_front_styles'), false, '1.0', 'all',1 );   // the original add_action
  remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array('http://www.spijkerbroek.me/wp-content/plugins/advance-wp-query-search-filter/js/awqsf-front.js','awsqf_front_styles'), false, '1.0', 'all',1 );
  remove_action( 'awqsf', array('http://www.spijkerbroek.me/wp-content/plugins/advance-wp-query-search-filter/js/awqsf-front.js','awsqf_front_styles'), false, '1.0', 'all',1 );
  remove_action( 'awqsf', array('http://www.spijkerbroek.me/wp-content/plugins/advance-wp-query-search-filter/js/awqsf-front.js','wp_enqueue_scripts'), false, '1.0', 'all',1 );
}
add_action( 'wp_awqsf_scripts', 'my_deregister_scripts', 1 );
```

Can somebody get me into the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

What you need is simple **dequeue** the script. (I said dequeue and not deregister once the script is immediately enqueued and simply deregister it will throw an error, because WP will try to enqueue a non registered script).

But to dequeue something is necessary that *something* is first enqueued, so normally you have to look at the priority on which the enqueue function is called on `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` and use a lower priority (higher priority number).

In your case, look at this line:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'awsqf_front_styles'),false,'1.0','all',1);
```

this is **wrong**. Plugin author is using the parameters for `wp_enqueue_script` in the function `add_action`.

If you look in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) `add_action` accept 4 arguments:

```
add_action($tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args)
```

So plugin author are using `false` as `$priority` and `'1.0'` as `$accepted_args`. `'all'` and `1` will be ignored at all.

Off course this is an error, but WordPress can do its work despite it, using the default priority that is **`10`**.

Once you know this, you can just use a lower priority (higher priority number) and dequeue the script:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_awsqf_front_script', 30);

function remove_awsqf_front_script() {
  wp_dequeue_script('awqsf-frontjs');
}
```

That's all.

Comment: You also use `wp_dequeue_script`. The OP was using (trying to use) `wp_deregister_script`.

Comment: This is because the plugin registers the script and immediately after enqueue it. If I `wp_deregister_script` I'll get an error because WP try to enqueue a non-registered script. So if deregistering is mandatory it must be done after the dequeuing. But I think that the scope is remove the script from page and dequeing is enough for that. @s_ha_dum

Comment: Yep, I get it. Just pointing out a difference in the approaches that might otherwise be missed.

Comment: Sure. First line of answer is there for that, but maybe is not very highlighted. But now I'm lazy to edit answer, upvoted both your comments hoping it's an effective highlight :) @s_ha_dum