# Deregister scripts on unnecessary pages using remove_action

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, actions, wp-enqueue-style

> **To all would-be close-voters:** This question is not a duplicate, because I need to remove all scripts added by plugin using `remove_action`.
>
> In [Very stubborn wp_register_script / add_action vs remove](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116535/very-stubborn-wp-register-script-add-action-vs-remove) used `wp_dequeue_script` function to remove scripts one by one, but I need to remove them all (which was added by plugin using `add_action`) using `remove_action`!

`wp_dequeue_script` function can't remove custom code like this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'print_style');

function print_style() {
    echo '<style>body { margin: 0; }</style>';
}
```

I have installed WP Polls plugin. I am using it in some of the pages and need to deregister its styles and scripts on other pages.

I found some code in the plugin which registers scripts:

#### Function: Enqueue Polls JavaScripts/CSS

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts');
function poll_scripts() {
    // code
}
```

So for deregistering its scripts i am using next code in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'deregister_polls_scripts_and_styles' );

function deregister_polls_scripts_and_styles() {
    if ( is_home() ) {
        remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts');
    }
}
```

So it must deregister polls scripts on homepage, but id does not. What i am doing wrong?

**P.S. 1**

Scripts are removing in this case:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wc_deregister_polls_scripts_and_styles' );

function wc_deregister_polls_scripts_and_styles() {
    remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'poll_head_scripts');
}
```

But i need to remove it on some pages like this:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wc_deregister_polls_scripts_and_styles' );

function wc_deregister_polls_scripts_and_styles() {
    if ( is_page('developers') ) {
        remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'poll_head_scripts');
    }
}
```

So in this case it does not work.

I have installed another plugin and all works fine in this case. Same actions, BUT all works:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wc_deregister_scripts_and_styles' );

function wc_deregister_scripts_and_styles() {
    if ( !is_home() && !is_tax('brand') ) {
        remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uag_frontend_styles', 999 );
        remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'uag_footer_scripts');
    }
}
```

**P. S. 2**

This is another plugin.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uag_frontend_styles', 999);
function uag_frontend_styles() {

    /* main stylesheet */
    wp_register_style( 'uag_style', uag_url . 'css/uag.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('uag_style');
    }
```

This is Polls:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts');
function poll_scripts() {
    global $text_direction;
    if(@file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory().'/polls-css.css')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('wp-polls', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/polls-css.css', false, '2.63', 'all');
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style('wp-polls', plugins_url('wp-polls/polls-css.css'), false, '2.63', 'all');
    }
    if('rtl' == $text_direction) {
        if(@file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory().'/polls-css-rtl.css')) {
            wp_enqueue_style('wp-polls-rtl', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/polls-css-rtl.css', false, '2.63', 'all');
        } else {
            wp_enqueue_style('wp-polls-rtl', plugins_url('wp-polls/polls-css-rtl.css'), false, '2.63', 'all');
        }
    }
    $poll_ajax_style = get_option('poll_ajax_style');
    $pollbar = get_option('poll_bar');
    wp_enqueue_script('wp-polls', plugins_url('wp-polls/polls-js.js'), array('jquery'), '2.63', true);
// Other same code
}
```

Comment: I have installed another plugin and used same solution and all works...

Comment: can you check if you are using a static home page in that case you need to use the conditional tag `is_front_page()` instead of `is_home()`. If everything is fine with that, can you please share the code written in plugin to enqueue the  js file.

Answer (score 3):

An action can be removed in time that pass since it is added to it is fired. So after is added, before is fired.

You say the plugin has thiss code:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts');

function poll_scripts() {
    // code
}
```

But you don't say if this code is inside a function hooked somewhere.

If it is **not** in any function, the action is added as soon the plugins is loaded, so you (so before theme is loaded) so if you do it from a theme, you can remove this action everywhere before `wp_head()`, first hook you have available on theme is `after_setup_theme`,

So this one will work:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'remove_poll_scripts');

function remove_poll_scripts() {
  if ( is_home() ) remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts');
}
```

if in your `functions.php` you just write

```
remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts');
```

It will work because `functions.php` is loaded *after* the plugin and *before* `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` is fired: so you are perfectly in time but you can't check in which page remove the scripts.

Moreover, if you try to do the exactly same thing from a plugin, and in your plugin file you write

```
remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts');
```

without wrapping it in any hook, it *can* fail: no one can assure your plugin is not loaded before the plugin that add the script and in that case you try to remove the action before it is added.

Comment: Ok, this is good idea, but in this case i cant check on which page i need to remove scripts. See P.S. 1 in main question.

Comment: Use `template_redirect` instead of `after_setup_theme`. See the edit. @Alexander

Comment: But why same solution worked on another plugin?

Comment: Probably other plugin handle the enqueue differently. @Alexander

Comment: See P. S. 2 plz

Comment: So only difference - style registration...

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought here - try moving back the priority on your action. Without the priority, it's going to be defaulting to 10, same as the original registration. Because of the way child themes work, that means you are firing the deregister before the register/enqueue takes place.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'deregister_polls_scripts_and_styles', 99 );
```

Comment: So only way to remove them all - use mechanism like this wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );? So i need to dequeue every script manually?

Comment: This thing does not working.

Comment: All working if i only use remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'poll_scripts'); in my functions.php without any remove action.